# rosjava compilation problem

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, rosjava-core, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

after use ./gradlew install

i take this

rosjava_core/rosjava_messages/build/generated-src/explore/ExploreState.java:9: package robot_actions does not exist
void setStatus(robot_actions.ActionStatus value);

robot_actions is depricated...

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
ROS FUERTE

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38047/rosjava-compilation-problem/) by [Koibi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1560/koibi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-07-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the package "robot_actions" is not in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1